# Print Values from a List

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm exploring Python as late as now, so please bear with me if you find this question relatively easy. Basically, what I want to display or print are the maximum and minimum values in the array/list, but alas, I can't seem to get the values from it. Thanks in advance for your help guys.

```
def f(x):
  y = x*x*x - 4*x + 1
  return y
  
# assign the f(x) value to variables a,b,c,d and pass them to a list or array called max_min(data)

x = -2.0
print("f(", x ,") = ", f(x))
a = f(x)

x = -0.75
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
b = f(x)

x = 0.5
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
c = f(x)

x = 2.0
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
d = f(x)

def max_min(data):              # initializing max_min(data) list
  max_val = data[0]             # initializing the position of the variable in the array
  min_val = data[0]             # initializing the position of the variable in the array
  for num in data:              
    if num > max_val:           # testing the initial value of num (0 by default)
      max_val = num
    elif num < min_val:
        min_val = num
  return max_val, min_val

print(max_min([a, b, c, d]))    # 
print("----------------------------------------------")
print("The maximum value in the list = ")
print("The minimum value in the list = ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
print(max_min([a, b, c, d]))    # 
print("----------------------------------------------")
max_num, min_num = max_min([a,b,c,d])
print(max_num)
print(min_num)
```

The reason for this is because you are returning two values from the same function, it will become a tuple. To easily print the values of the tuple separately, you just assign the values to two separate variables.

Comment: The last 3 lines of codes perfectly display what I need. Without changes from my original code, the additional 2 variables are the missing pieces of the puzzle. Pardon my limited knowledge, but I want to ask how the list know where to assign the max and the min values in the two separate variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean how it knows which variable to assign the values to, it just assigns them in the order of the tuple. For example, if you do num1, num2 = (1,2), num1 would be equal to 1 and num2 to 2. But if you do num1, num2 = (2,1), then num1 would be equal to 2 and num2 to 1. So it is simply because of the order you return your values from the max_min function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
  y = x*x*x - 4*x + 1
  return y
  
# assign the f(x) value to variables a,b,c,d and pass them to a list or array called max_min(data)

x = -2.0
print("f(", x ,") = ", f(x))
a = f(x)

x = -0.75
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
b = f(x)

x = 0.5
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
c = f(x)

x = 2.0
print("f(", x, ") = ", f(x))
d = f(x)

def max_min(data):              # initializing max_min(data) list
  max_val = data[0]             # initializing the position of the variable in the array
  min_val = data[0]             # initializing the position of the variable in the array
  for num in data:              
    if num > max_val:           # testing the initial value of num (0 by default)
      max_val = num
    elif num < min_val:
        min_val = num
  return max_val, min_val

a, b, c, d = 10, 20, 30, 5

maxmin = max_min([a, b, c, d])
print(maxmin)    # 
print("----------------------------------------------")
print("The maximum value in the list = " + str(maxmin[0]))
print("The minimum value in the list = " + str(maxmin[1]))
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't call `str` on a `print` argument. Use `print("The maximum value in the list =", maxmin[0])` or an f-string.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I was considering the backwards compatibility. I usually use an f-string.

Comment: Python 3.6 that introduced them is now 6 years old, you can safely use them in your answers ;)

Comment: I tried your approach, and it returns not as I expected, since the code reassigns and declare new values for variables a,b,c,d. The values to be tested should be the max_val and min_val, or the values of f(x). But I learned something from this approach, so thanks as well.

Comment: @ykobure This was for trying purposes, you can simply remove that line. You are welcome.